# How to change default text editor for all kind of text-based files, no matter what extension is?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I know Finder has built-in option to change default application but this is only for that extension. I want to make available my editor (MacVim) for all kind of text files. Such as .html, .xml, ... .gitignore etc., even unknown extensions *like.this*.

I have tried [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) but looks like not working anymore.

I also tried:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=org.vim.MacVim;}'
$ defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices
{
    LSHandlers =     (
                {
            LSHandlerContentType = "public.plain-text";
            LSHandlerRoleAll = "org.vim.MacVim";
        }
    );
}
```

*and with different UTIs like `public.text`, `public.utf8-plain-text`. No luck.*

Any help appreciated. I don't want to see TextEdit anymore...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123834) on Ask Different mentions your method to be outdated. It also points to [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220496) that is supposed to work on newer macOS versions (those that came after Mavericks).

`defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers -array-add \
'{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=org.vim.MacVim;}'`

Notice the difference between `com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add` in your code and `com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers -array-add` in the offered solution.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that **a restart is needed** (linked answer does mention this though).

Also, please note (see this answer's comments) that the OP apparently needed to export all defaults with `defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers > defualts.txt`, change all apps to `org.vim.MacVim` via a text-editor, before re-importing them via `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers "$(cat defualts.txt)"`

Comment: Thanks but not working. I even exported whole defaults with `defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers > defualts.txt` and changed all apps with org.vim.MacVim with my editor, then imported by typing `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers "$(cat defualts.txt)"`. Still not working, and opens TextEdit. I don't know why.

Comment: Well, I actually needed to restart... That's working now, thanks. I'm going to accept this answer but if someone want to change them all, need to use my method.