# How do I make NeoVim my default text/code editor?

Tags: macos, vim, neovim

**Is there a way to make NeoVim as default text/code editor** (without any bad side effects) **?**
Trust me, I looked to lots of StackOverflow question/answers and tried a few things but nothing worked for me.

**Note**: I'm on **macOS Big Sur** (version **11.2.1**). What I want is when I click on files to open in NeoVim.



--> **For example**, in **~/.zshrc** (and added to ~/.bash_profile also just in case) **I have**:

**Note**: zsh is my default shell

```
alias nvim=$HOME/nvim-osx64/bin/nvim
export EDITOR="nvim"
export VISUAL="nvim"
```

When I do `set` in Terminal it shows:

```
EDITOR=nvim
VISUAL=nvim
```

**And yes**, I quit and started the terminal (I'm using **iTerm2**). I even reboot.

--> I will place **my $PATH** here just in case it has anything to do it that. When I do `echo $PATH` it shows:

[image]

--> And, just in case someone suggests:
I can't `Select a File` > `Open With...` and select NeoVim as default text editor, since that option doesn't show and I can't do `Choose Other` since I can't select NeoVim in that way.



**If anyone needs more information, please say and I will edit the question with that info. Thanks!**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370584/set-textmate-as-the-default-text-editor-on-mac-os-x/65359498#65359498

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011299/how-to-change-default-text-editor-for-all-kind-of-text-based-files-no-matter-wh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while I found the answer to my own question, **here it is how you can set NeoVim in Mac as the default text editor**. Now, you will be able click on files and opening them in NeoVim:

**Some people recommended me to have a look at the follow links:**

> https://gist.github.com/Huluk/5117702

> https://superuser.com/questions/139352/mac-os-x-how-to-open-vim-in-terminal-when-double-click-on-a-file

**That didn't work for me but it served as a reference to look up related topics (automator + neovim).**

After a while, I discover this blog:

> https://blog.schembri.me/post/neovim-everywhere-on-macos/

Go and have a look at the blog, but **here it is how you do it:**

1. Launch Automator (Finder -> Applications -> `Automator`)
2. New Document -> Choose a type for your document: `Application`
3. In Actions search for `Run AppleScript` and drag that to where it says something like "Drag actions here..."
4. Delete the default example of AppleScript
5. Copy and Paste the code in the blog (where it says NeoVim.app) to where it previous had the default code
6. Save the new Automator app (save as aplicattion format). `Save it in the Applications folder`
7. Right-Click a file type you wish to open every time you click on them (e.g. .php file). Select `Get Info` or do `cmd + i`, it will open informations about that file.  Scroll to wher it says `Open With` and select `Other`. Then just go to `Aplicattions folder` and select your new NeoVim "app".
8. Do the same to other file types if you wish.
9. You can now double click on your PHP files (or others if you did the same) and open them in NeoVim. Enjoy!

**Note:** You really need to do `Right-Click`, `Get Info` and look for `Open With` to change in all files with that extension. If you skip `Get Info` and just Right-Click + Open With, it will only work for that specific file...

This is the code from the blog:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set cmd to "nvim"
  if input is not {} then
    set filePath to POSIX path of input
    set cmd to "nvim \"" & filePath & "\""
  end if
    
  tell application "iTerm"
    create window with default profile
    tell the current window
      tell the current session to write text cmd
    end tell
  end tell
end run
```

This would open a new window even if you already had one open.

I change it so that it would open in a tab:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set cmd to "nvim"
    if input is not {} then
        set filePath to POSIX path of input
        set cmd to "nvim \"" & filePath & "\""
    end if
    
    tell application "iTerm"
        tell the current window
            create tab with default profile
            tell the current session to write text cmd
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

**Note:** I'm using iTerm2. If you are using another Terminal Emulator, change where it says iTerm to the name of your terminal...

Answer (score 4):

Setting variables in the terminal will not affect the GUI file associations. To do that you have to change the OS's file associations.

Though it appears to be a small project and unsupported, I've had a good experience using [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti). It's a wrapper around the Apple file extension API. The configuration did take me a minute to figure out. I'll post it if I can find it.

Answer (score 1):

to anyone want similar thing for NeoVim with Alacritty, here is a full Applescript without using any shell commands. it can open any file you want with alacritty and neovim.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set cmd to "nvim"
    if input is not {} then
        set filePath to POSIX path of input
        set cmd to "nvim \"" & filePath & "\""
    end if

    my alacritty_win()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke cmd
        key code 36
    end tell
end run

on alacritty_win()
    set _running to (application "Alacritty" is running)
    tell application "Alacritty" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat while (name of first application process whose frontmost is true) is not "Alacritty"
            delay 0.05
        end repeat
        set _alacritty to first application process whose frontmost is true
        -- If Alacritty was running, create a new window to run command
        if _running then
            tell _alacritty to set _target to (count windows) + 1
            keystroke "n" using {command down}
        else
            set _target to 1
        end if
        -- Wait for wanted window count
        tell _alacritty
            repeat while (count windows) < _target
                delay 0.05
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end alacritty_win
```

> Note: you have to give the application 'neovim.app' access to accessibility in the mac settings.

Please follow @DGF's answer to apply this script and create application with name like 'neovim.app' and use it as normal app.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) on MacOS, I found a pretty simple way to accomplish this using the remote control feature.

First you need the following set in your `kitty.conf`:

```
allow_remote_control yes
listen_on unix:/tmp/mykitty
```

Using Automator like in @DGF's answer, I created an Application with the "Run Shell Script" action, and this is the script:

```sh
if [ -z "$(pgrep kitty)" ]
then
    open /Applications/kitty.app
    sleep 3 # allow ample time to startup and start listening
fi

/usr/local/bin/kitty @ --to=unix:/tmp/mykitty-$(pgrep kitty) launch --type=os-window nvim "$@"
```

Save that as an application somewhere, and select it from "Open with"!

Note: to be honest, the logic to handle starting up kitty if it's not already running is a little flaky. But it seems to work great when kitty is already running, which of course it is most of the time for me. Also, it doesn't work at all if kitty is running but has no windows. :\

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the accepted answer; I don't want to install iTerm for this to work. This AppleScript opens nvim in Terminal:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set cmd to "nvim"
  if input is not {} then
    set filePath to POSIX path of input
    set cmd to "nvim \"" & filePath & "\""
  end if
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script with command cmd
  end tell
end run
```

It can be easily modified to open in another terminal (Alacritty here):

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set cmd to "alacritty -e nvim"
  if input is not {} then
    set filePath to POSIX path of input
    set cmd to "alacritty -e nvim \"" & filePath & "\""
  end if
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script with command cmd
  end tell
end run
```